# Cannot call Java Filter from an HTML page

Tags: java, html, servlets, web-applications, servlet-filters

I'm triyng to learn about filters. I use netbens 8.02.

I have a silmple html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <form action="f">
                <label for="username">User: </label><input name ="username" type="text">
                <label for="password">Password: </label><input name ="password" type="password">
                <input type="submit" value="Vai">
            </form>
        </nav>

        <section id ="page">

        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I'm trying to call a filter called "f" but everytime I build and run the broject and I try to load the filter after trying to login I got the 404 message:

```
type Status report

message /Filtri/f

description The requested resource is not available.
```

this is my web.xml file: (built by netbeans)

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <web-app version="3.1"
> xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
> http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
>     <filter>
>         <filter-name>f</filter-name>
>         <filter-class>f</filter-class>
>     </filter>
>     <filter-mapping>
>         <filter-name>f</filter-name>
>         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
>     </filter-mapping>
>     <session-config>
>         <session-timeout>
>             30
>         </session-timeout>
>     </session-config> </web-app>
```

This is my project hierachy:[Project hierachy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbyHN.png)

Can you help me?

Comment: You have to mention fully qualified class of filter against <filter-class>

Comment: Also one more thong : A Servlet filter is an object that can intercept HTTP requests targeted at your web application, you should create a Servlet instead of Filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Filter`'s intercept or pre-process a request, but the request still needs to go to an resource (a `servlet`, a `jsp`, or `html` page) otherwise, the server will respond with a `404`

You're requesting a resource at `f`, but although the filter might intercept the request, once the filter has finished processing, the server is still trying to send you to `f` which isn't anything in your context.